# Is it possible for UMDF driver to write to a file?

Tags: c++, driver, umdf

For a case where I want to log a string to a text file, say in C:\log.txt, is this possible in UMDF driver? considering that UMDF drivers have limited UAC.

Comment: UDMF drivers run in user mode under the LOCAL SERVICE account.  UAC does not apply.  Pick a folder and use Explorer to add write access for that account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot log to `C:\`. Standard users are not allowed to write to that location.

The reason the default security settings on `C:\` prevent standard users from writing to `C:\` is to stop applications from writing to `C:\`.

You can write to locations you *can* write to, e.g.

- **[GetTempPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppathw)**
- [SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath)

## See also

- [How can I make UMDF driver write to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54919618/how-can-i-make-umdf-driver-write-to-file)